# Color background in Macvim editor

Tags: vim, macvim

Basically, The background behind the line numbers are darker than the background behind the code, as you can see from the picture below. The background behind the codes has a slightly lighter color than that behind the line numbers. I hope I describe this well enough for you to understand.

[image]

I am just wondering what code should I write onto `.vimrc` file in order to capture the same effect  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to put the command `highlight` in your `.vimrc` followed by certain arguments. To learn about the arguments that `highlight` takes, type `:help :highlight` and press Return. This will open [the help for the `highlight` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight).

This is the particular format of `highlight` that you want:

> ```
> :hi[ghlight] [default] {group-name} {key}={arg} ..
>           Add a highlight group, or change the highlighting for
>           an existing group.
>           See |highlight-args| for the {key}={arg} arguments.
>           See |:highlight-default| for the optional [default]
>           argument.
> ```

You can find the correct `{group-name}` to use with `:help highlight-groups`. As [romainl said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24479979/578288), the group names for the line numbers at the left are `LineNr` and `CursorLineNr`.

And what to put for the `{key}={arg}` arguments? Well, check `:help highlight-args` as the help text suggested. The key represents what aspect of the text should be changed (e.g. italic or not, or the foreground color), and the arg represents what it should be changed to (e.g. italic, or bright red). In your case, you want to change the background color, which is controlled by `ctermbg` for terminals and `guibg` for GUIs.

Run `:highlight Normal` to learn the background color you want. You should see something like `guibg=grey10`. So try setting the `guibg` (background color in the GUI) of your line numbers to the color `grey10` in your `.vimrc`:

```
highlight LineNr guibg=grey10
highlight CursorLineNr guibg=grey10
```

### Edit

It sounds like you want to change the code background color, not the line number background color. To do that, write the same command, but use the highlight group that represents normal code instead of the `LineNr` and `CursorLineNr` highlight groups that represent line numbers. If you look at [`highlight-groups` help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#highlight-groups), you can see that the highlight group for code in general is called `Normal`. So write

```
highlight Normal guibg=grey
```

, changing `grey` to whatever color you want.

If you aren’t sure what color you want, and you just know that you want it to be the same as some other color, run `:highlight {group-name}` to look up the settings for that group name, and look for the background color key within it. For example, if you want to make the code background color the same as the line number background color, run `:highlight LineNr`. You will see something like `guibg=#242424`, which would mean to use `#242424` as the color.

Comment: Please see the comment below. I am not sure whether `CursorLineNr` has anything to do with changing the background color of the block of codes. I am sure that `LineNr` is doing what I want. But not sure about `CursorLineNr`.

Comment: According to the help about `CursorLineNr` within `highlight-groups`, it is “like `LineNr` when `'cursorline'` or `'relativenumber'` is set for the cursor line.” If you run `:set cursorline` to always highlight the current line, the current line’s background color can be set separately from other lines’. If you type `:set cursorline?` and get `nocursorline`, then you have that feature off, so `CursorLineNr` doesn’t matter.

Comment: Okay. I probably have explained it badly. I am not trying to make the `cursorline` to have a gray background. I am trying to make the background of the entire script to have a gray color. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain how the set the background color of the main code, instead of the background color of the line numbers. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can find `LineNr` and `CursorLineNr` listed under `:help highlight-groups`.

You will need to add/change the corresponding lines in your colorscheme.

Comment: I want to kindly ask what should the values of LineNr and CursorLineNr be ?

Comment: Use the `guibg` value of the `Normal` highlight group. It's `grey10`.

Comment: Sorry. I just started learning vim. Is it possible that you can just write me the exact code for this. And where can I find help highlight-groups ?

Comment: @Chinegro To open help, from Normal mode, type exactly `:help highlight-groups` and press Return.

Comment: Vim is sometimes sensitive to whitespace between operators. `guibg = black` is not the same as `guibg=black`. Try removing the spaces, to match [`highlight` help’s](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight) “`{key}={arg}`” format which also doesn’t have spaces.